# Extract urls-links from pop-up which appears on top of webpage using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, html

How to extract the url-links from pop-up which appears on top of webpage.

I tried using wget,curl and lynx but we will get contents of original page no the pop-up.

looking for efficient solution to extract the links from webpage and dig into it  to search particular pattern using Shell Script

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many suitable tools, and those you mentioned will not work.  The popup is probably JavaScript (though there are other possibilities).  A quick web search for "scrape links from javascript popup" will show several examples, with no easy solutions.

Here are a few:

People with unsolved problems:

- [How to scrape content rendered in popup window with javascript: links using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838740/how-to-scrape-content-rendered-in-popup-window-with-javascript-links-using-scra)
- [Scraping Ajax / JS pop-up](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=954061)

People discussing solutions (with caveats):

- [Web Scraping Ajax and Javascript Sites](http://blog.databigbang.com/web-scraping-ajax-and-javascript-sites/)
- [A Guide to Web Scraping Tools](http://www.garethjames.net/a-guide-to-web-scrapping-tools/)